# как работает SharedPreferences

Tags: android-shared-preferences

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("AppPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor PrefsEditor = preferences.edit();
        PrefsEditor.putString("name", email);
        PrefsEditor.putString("password", password);
        String email1=preferences.getString("name", "");
        String password1=preferences.getString("password", "");
        Toast pass = Toast.makeText(this, email1 +" "+ password1, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        pass.show();
```

объясните пожалуйста что тут не правильно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

После внесения изменений через `putString` и другие надо выполнять сохранение

```
PrefsEditor.commit();
```

Comment: а как потом удалить значения

Comment: @Sergey, на вопрос я ответил.

Comment: хорошо, спасибо

Comment: @Sergey, вам помог мой ответ? Если да отметьте его верным, поставив галочку :) Чтобы другие нашли решение. Ну и как бы у нас принято так выражать благодарность